# Can RabbitMQ SDK be used to operate Azure Service Bus like Kafka for EventHubs?

Tags: rabbitmq, azureservicebus, amqp

Azure EventHubs (on tier standard) allows you to use the Kafka SDK. Does Azure Service Bus has a similar feature for RabbitMQ given that both work with AMQP?